# What is the standard way to configure an ItemTemplate without violating the Item separation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

In using WPF for a while, this is actually the first time that I've come across a situation where I have an ItemTemplate for a ListBox that I want to be configurable based on properties outside the item itself. The problem came up when I wanted to have a Font selector dialog where the user could click a chechbox to enable the font previews (I actually changed my mind about this implementation, but I'd still like to know the answer).

It seems, because the DataTemplate may be used in any situation where that type is provided, it's considered good practice, not to bind to any parameters outside the item's configuration (seems like the code to bind to properties of a containing DataTemplate is particularly obtuse.)

I was wondering how I was supposed to implement this kind of situation. The code below works, but the binding is to a visual element, whereas I would rather bind to the property in the ViewModel.

```
<Window x:Class="ScreenWriter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox Name="ShowPreview" IsChecked="{Binding IsShowPreviewChecked}">
                Show Preview
            </CheckBox>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ShowPreview}">
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="{Binding}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBlock.Style>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This doesn't seem like an unusual situation, but I can't find any solution that isn't prefixed with "this is a clever way to get around what you're not supposed to do".
Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no 'best practice' solution for this problem.

As you wrote, "the DataTemplate may be used in any situation where that type is provided ... not to bind to any parameters outside the item's configuration".

Binding/DataContext are based on LogicalTree. So your Trigger binding trys to find the closest datacontext on the tree (in this case your ListItem DataContext = FontFamily )

You have to make same 'jump' from this 'LogicalTree Island' to the main Tree - like your control/element did a jump.
So the real question is, how could you change the binding source smoothly.

You could bind Target element DataContext directly (CheckBox has no DataContext, but its grandparent - Windows has):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsShowPreviewChecked, ElementName=ShowPreview}" Value="True" >
```

or just find ListItem ancestor directly:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsShowPreviewChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True" >
```

If you will use this jump many times, you will try to use *BindingProxy*
which will provide a shortcut for your bindings:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    public object Context
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Context", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Add this proxy as resouce:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <this:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" Context="{Binding}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and your binding is:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Context.IsShowPreviewChecked, Source={StaticResource Proxy}}" Value="True" >
```

Do not forget add *INotifyPropertyChanged* Interface to your ViewModel